# Set active page in bootstrap pager (pagination)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

i am using bootstrap pager for pagination. For some reason, i prefare the pager over the pagination feature. when i put the `<ul class="pager">` inside the pagination class. It does not work and get mess up instead. I remove the pagination and the pager is working fine. I am generating my links dynamically like below.

```
<ul class="pager">
     <li class="previous disabled"><a href="#">&larr; Previous</a></li>
       <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
       <li>@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))</li>
     <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="#"> Next &rarr;</a></li>
</ul>
```

my `PageLinks` is the html helper below.

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                              PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                              Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); //Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("active");

                result.Append(tag.ToString());

            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());

        }
```

My problem is i want to set the active selection property as returned from the htmlhelper method. I want to change the color when active. try adding

```
<style type="text/css">
.li .active{
    background-color : blue
}
</style>
```

to my layout head tag. It does not work. try everything just to get an effect , but it fails. I try adding to my bootstrap.css bcos i notice under `.pager` there is no active property. It does not respond also.Please how do i achieve this? how do i make it work? any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Actually i wanted to use the pagination class but it was not working totally. I try the default example yet it does not work.  When i try the default example from boot strap , this is how it displays. However, the pager class works, so i have no option than to use the pager.

[image]

Comment: This AddCssClass method, is it a user defined method?? Because in JQuery we use jQuery addClass() Method, to add any css class.

Comment: AddCssClass is a method from the microsoft TabBuider Class . It dynamically had class to the existing css classeses. I followed the example by Adam Freeman in his book of pro asp.net mcv 4 and this really works amazingly. You can add the class and set it in ur css file. See <a href ="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.addcssclass(v=vs.111).aspx"> for AddCssClass.  @Nayana_Das if you have any alternative please explain to me . I dont seem to get this going now.

Comment: Sorry, to add css class, I usually use jQuery addClass() or javascript className, both are too easy to work with, so, i didn't thought of any alternative methods. Hope any one comes with another method. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this html and css code i hops it help.

```
    .pager li.active > a, .pager li.active > span{
        background-color:#eee;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="pagination pagination-large">
    <ul class="pager"><li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://www.bootply.com/s5KC9cu4E0)

Comment: thanks for the help. I am adding the `<li class="active">` dynamically. it works when i add manually. Howevern it does not dynamically.  see my code above `tag.AddCssClass("active");
` . Thank you